# How to get the autocomplete to fill in full_methods instead of just full

Tags: vim

I write a lot of methods "like_this". When I press "l< Tab >" to autocomplete all I am offered is "like". Is there a way to configure VIM to give me "like_this" as an option?

Kindest of Regards,

-- Jack

Comment: vim tab completion is not done with <TAB>, so there must be some other system at work here. Try with a blank vimrc

Comment: The same thing happens with ^P in insert mode. I just remapped it to TAB.

Comment: If you're using `^P` completion, do you have more things in your buffer (or other buffers) that start with the same prefix?  `like_this` and `likethat` with some combinations of `completeopt` will complete to `like` because it's the longest common prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Randy Morris's comment is worth exploring, type `set completeopt?` to see what you have then `:help completeopt` to explore your choices.

But I think that's probably because your vim considers `_` as a word delimiter by default. Check it out by typing `:set iskeyword?`, mine says `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`.

Type `:help iskeyword` for more information.